# TypeScript Compiler API to access base interfaces or classes

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I working with `TypeScript` Compiler API on small plugin,
and I am curious how to get from `NodeObject` all interfaces or classes which it extends ?

I have not found useful example in `TypeScript` Compiler API documentation ...

Any help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer,

It is possible to do using `heritageClauses`:

```js
if (node.heritageClauses) {
   for(const hc of node.heritageClauses) {
      console.log("heritage clause: " + hc.getText()); // prints "extends ..."
   }
}
```